¿Como deberia pasar propiedades de una pantalla padre a sus componentes hijos, en React Native y TypeScript?
Tengo esta stack de navegación
const StackDetalles = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
function StackGroupDetalles() {
    return (
        <StackDetalles.Navigator initialRouteName="MainDetalles">
            <StackDetalles.Screen name="MainDetalles" component={MainDetalles} options={{
                headerShown: false
            }} />
            <StackDetalles.Screen name="Scanner" component={Scanner} options={{
                headerShown: false
            }} />
            <StackDetalles.Screen name="TopTabGroupDetalles" component={TopTabGroupDetalles} options={{
                headerShown: false
            }} />
        </StackDetalles.Navigator>
    );
}

Contiene un TopTabMaterial
const TopTabDetalles = createMaterialTopTabNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
function TopTabGroupDetalles() {
    return (
        <TopTabDetalles.Navigator initialRouteName="Detalles" >
            <TopTabDetalles.Screen name="Detalles" component={Detalles} />
            <TopTabDetalles.Screen name="MantenimientosEquipo" component={MantenimientosEquipo} />
        </TopTabDetalles.Navigator>

    );
}

Este TopTab tiene dos atributos:
TopTabGroupDetalles: {
        eiInfoEquipo: infoequipo,
        eiMantenimientos: mantenimientosequipo
    };

Y al navegar a este TopTab se supone que va inicialmente a la pantalla de Detalles pero deberia precargar la ventana de Mantenimientos, la idea es que muestre los detalles y en la ventana continua esté los detalles de mantenimiento. Entonces estas screen tienen los atributos individuales del TopTab para que cada uno tenga la informacion que devuelve el api.
Detalles: {
        eiInfoEquipo: infoequipo
    };
MantenimientosEquipo : {
        eiMantenimientos: mantenimientosequipo
    };

Asi navego al TopTab:
try {
    const informacionEquipo: infoequipo = await getInfoEquipo(codigoEquipo, accessToken, refreshToken)
    const mantenimientosEquipo: mantenimientosequipo = await getMantenimientosEquipo(codigoEquipo, accessToken, refreshToken)
    setCodigoEquipo("")
    navigation.navigate("TopTabGroupDetalles", {
      eiInfoEquipo: informacionEquipo,
      eiMantenimientos: mantenimientosEquipo
    })
}

Entonces no se como pasar los parámetros al momento de navegar, porque navego y paso los parámetros al TopTab pero este inicializa directamente los Detalles y los Mantenimientos pero como no le puedo pasar los parámetros, no se como hacer, o si debería cambiar la estructura de navegación, por favor necesito ayuda.
En este TopTab
const TopTabDetalles = createMaterialTopTabNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
function TopTabGroupDetalles() {
    return (
        <TopTabDetalles.Navigator initialRouteName="Detalles" >
            <TopTabDetalles.Screen name="Detalles" component={Detalles} />
            <TopTabDetalles.Screen name="MantenimientosEquipo" component={MantenimientosEquipo} />
        </TopTabDetalles.Navigator>

    );
}

Se supone que las Screen tiene un atributo initialParams, pero desde este atributo no se como acceder a los atributos que se le envia al TopTab para pasalos a las Screens. Por favor alguna idea de como hacerlo!?

Pienso que puedes utilizar la propiedad route que contiene cada pantalla que utiliza React Navigation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop
Dentro de route se encuentra una propiedad llamada params que contiene el contenido pasado como parametro.
 import { RouteProp } from "@react-navigation/native";
 import { useEffect } from "react";

 type RoutesProps = {
   Scanner: undefined;
   MainDetalles: undefined;
   TopTabGroupDetalles: {
    eiInfoEquipo: any;
    eiMantenimientos: any;
  };
};

type RouteType = {
  route: RouteProp<RoutesProps, 'TopTabGroupDetalles'>;
  // navigation: StackNavigation;
}

function TopTabGroupDetalles({ route }: { route: RouteType }) {
    
      useEffect(() => {
         console.log(route.params)
      }, [])

      return (
          <TopTabDetalles.Navigator initialRouteName="Detalles" >
              <TopTabDetalles.Screen name="Detalles" component={Detalles} />
              <TopTabDetalles.Screen name="MantenimientosEquipo" component={MantenimientosEquipo} />
          </TopTabDetalles.Navigator>
      );
  }

Como estas utilizando typescript puedes utilizar RouteProp que es el tipo de dato del param mencionado. Si no quieres mayores complicaciones puedes utilizar any.
function TopTabGroupDetalles({ route }: { route: any }) {

